# Radiobutton in asp with jQuery

Tags: jquery, radio-button

this works:

```
<script>
    $("input:radio").change(function () {
        alert($(this).attr("name"));
    });
</script>
```

the result is :  ctl00$ctl00$cphBody$cphBody$RS_rbtItemGroup

but this not work:

```
<script>
    $("input[name=ctl00$ctl00$cphBody$cphBody$RS_rbtItemGroup]:radio").change(function () {
        alert($(this).attr("name"));
    });
</script>
```

could anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have "$" in the name, you need to add single quotes to you name query.  Try this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("input[name='ctl00$ctl00$cphBody$cphBody$RS_rbtItemGroup']:radio").change(function () {
            alert($(this).attr("name"));
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type='radio' name='ctl00$ctl00$cphBody$cphBody$RS_rbtItemGroup' value='yes'>Yes</input>
    <input type='radio' name='ctl00$ctl00$cphBody$cphBody$RS_rbtItemGroup' value='no'>No</input>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery API says the attribute equals selector takes [an unquoted single word or a quoted string](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/). Unfortunately it considers the `$` character as a non-word character so you have to put your name attribute value in quotes:

```
<script>
    $("input[name='ctl00$ctl00$cphBody$cphBody$RS_rbtItemGroup']:radio").change(function () {
        alert($(this).attr("name"));
    });
</script>
```

However, I recommend actually using the [attribute ends with selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) since the first part of your name is [generated by .NET](http://forums.asp.net/t/1772731.aspx?What+is+ctl00+ctl00+MainContent+MainContent+) and could potentially change if you adjust your layout:

```
<script>
    $("input[name$='$RS_rbtItemGroup']:radio").change(function () {
        alert($(this).attr("name"));
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but my layout won't change, and I don't know why when I add  ClientIDMode="Static" to my controls, It will be NOT rendered as name="$RS_rbtItemGroup". it will be name="ctl00$ctl00$cphBody$cphBody$RS_rbtItemGroup" so

Comment: My recommended code will work with `name="tl00$ctl00$cphBody$cphBody$RS_rbtItemGroup"` because it is using `$=` instead of `=` which checks what the attribute ends with instead of matching the entire attribute.

I consider this a better option because it is possible for .NET to add something besides `ctl00$ctl00$cphBody$cphBody$` to the beginning of the attribute.